# Function trims values after being passed in another function

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, watson

I would like have `renderData()` display the values from `max`. When I `console.log(max)` in `calculateData()` it displays all three maximum values from three JSON objects. However, when I return `max` in `renderData()` it only shows the first value. Why is this, and what can I do to make it display all three values instead of just one? Note: `data` is the json list of objects being passed.  Thank you!

```
function calculateData(data) {

    for (i in data) {

        var arr = [];
        var max;
        var obj = data[i].tones;

        obj.map(function(item) {
            var data = item.score;
            arr.push(data);
        })

        max = arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
            return Math.max(a, b);
        })

        //Returns an array containing dominant [emotion_tone, language_tone, social_tone]
        return renderData(max);
    }

}

function renderData(max) {
    console.log(max);
};
```

Comment: Rather than passing `max` (the maximum value) into your renderData function it sounds like you want to pass it `arr`

Comment: Also if you are returning from the function in first iteration of `for` loop then what is the point of loop ?

Comment: You actually return void with this statement `return renderData(max);...oh wait you return inside for loop...

Comment: don't abuse Array#map() like that. Check this out: `var arr = obj.map(function(item){ return item.score })` or in ES6 `var arr = obj.map(item => item.score);` and don't define a function inside a loop, unless it is inevitable *(like when you're using the block scope)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are intending?  It will iterate through the entire data object calculating a max for each iteration, collect them in an array, and then finally call the renderData func with that array.

```
function calculateData(data) {
   var maxes = [];
    for (i in data) {

        var arr = [];
        var max;
        var obj = data[i].tones;

        obj.map(function(item) {
            var data = item.score;
            arr.push(data);
        })

        maxes.push(arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
            return Math.max(a, b);
        }));

    }
    return renderData(maxes);

}

function renderData(max) {
    console.log(max);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a second array, `finalArray` and pushed each max into it:

```
 function calculateData(data) {

        var finalArr = [];

        for (i in data) {

            var arr = [];

            var max;

            data[i].tones.map(function(item) {
                arr.push(item.score);
            })

            var max = arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
                return Math.max(a, b);
            });

            finalArr.push(max);

            //Returns an array containing dominant [emotion_tone, language_tone, social_tone]
            // return renderData(max);
        }

        renderData(finalArr);

    }

    function renderData(finalArr) {
        console.log(finalArr);
    };
```

Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

Your error arises because the `return` statement inside the loop aborts the whole function, and therefore also the loop. But this whole function can be simplified/shortened quite a bit:

And as mentioned in the comments, don't define functions inside a loop *(unless it is inevitable)*, define the before the loop. I did this in by defining the functions `getScore` and `max` in my code.

```
//ES6
function calculateData(data) {
    var getScore = item => item.score, 
        max = (a,b) => Math.max(a,b),
        maxima = Object.values(data)
            .map(value => value.tones.map(getScore).reduce(max)); 

    return renderData(maxima);
}

//Or maybe you're more comfortable without Arrow functions
function calculateData(data) {
    function getScore(item){ return item.score }
    function max(a,b){ return Math.max(a,b) }

    var maxima = Object.values(data).map(function(value){ 
        return value.tones.map(getScore).reduce(max)
    }); 

    return renderData(maxima);
}
```

The only difference to your code is that `Object.values()` returns only own values of the object, whereas `for..in` iterates over all values of the object, own and inherited.